# window.requestAnimationFrame freezes browser window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to animate in JS using Canvas with the following code but the window.requestAnimationFrame runs tell it freezes the browser window:

```js
const renders = function(){
    //resize
document.getElementById('maingame').width = window.innerWidth
document.getElementById('maingame').height = window.innerHeight
document.getElementById('maingame').style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px'
document.getElementById('maingame').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px'
    //resize
    gr.clearRect(0,0,2000,2000) //clears
    
    //draws main c (Isolate)
    gr.save()
    gr.translate(window.innerWidth/2,window.innerHeight/2)
    gr.rotate(d)
    gr.drawImage(main0,-(main0.width*size)/2,-(main0.height*size)/2,main0.width*size,main0.height*size)
    gr.restore();
    camx = lerp(camx,x,0.1)
    camy = lerp(camy,y,0.1);
    gr.translate(x,y)//moves the camera
gr.drawImage(img4, 90+x, 130+y,img4.width*0.2,img4.height*0.2)
   for(let i = 0; i < things.length; i++){
    gr.drawImage(img3,things[i].x,things[i].y,img3.width*0.2,img3.height*0.2)

    window.requestAnimationFrame(renders); //recalls image to be drawn again asap
   }
   
};

// Game Start
window.requestAnimationFrame(renders)
```

I'm trying to build the basics for a engine to render game graphics in HTML 5 but I can't get this to work... (yes I know about phaser), does anyone know why it keeps freezes?

Comment: When you say 'crashes the browser window', I assume you mean the browser freezes, and not just the error received in the console?

Comment: yes, the browser tries running it tell it freezes. Thankyou, I I fixed it

Comment: @AndrewHansen share a working demo on jsfiddler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The request is in the wrong spot. You only want to request one animation frame after rendering.

```
for(let i = 0; i < things.length; i++){
    gr.drawImage(img3,things[i].x,things[i].y,img3.width*0.2,img3.height*0.2)
} // move this curly brace up !!!!
window.requestAnimationFrame(renders); // for next render
```

Comment: thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that, this issue has been plugging me for over a day